# How do I find the nodeid of the node issuing a lightning network invoice?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing, core-lightning, lightning-rfc

I recently got an BOLT11 invoice from a store. For example this one:

```
LNBC13934430N1PWJUJEZPP5K7FLC2M5CLHTWMTF3HZDN7VVRCA4RNFAFA89F2D6KGYWW4JCSDAQDZ62PSKJEPQW3HJQ4RGV5SYC6T8DP6XU6TWVUSYXMMWVEJHYETWVDJJQ2Z0WFJX2U3QF9ZR5GZ5F3PNZWFD25UY54Z39YXQZURCQP2RZJQG8ZM9WXGVHZPMUQEWY9J9KDQNRVLZHPCWM6S8CVLC2CKRDNELE42Z9U5VQQY3SQQYQQQQL8QQQQPJQQ9Q6KM84F7KTW6UV574UR2LFNKZLM7VNK8NJRZV20JD8SAW6FZ3TQGSZE6YUT0X2UXGDGYJZGTXEFSQSSEVTKFF97P3TER5K23ZPHDDXHQQ95UT4N
```

Luckily I my node was able to find a route to the destination but if it wouldn't? How could I find out the `nodeid` to open and fund a direct payment channel with the store? They did not say anything about their nodeid on their website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightning invoices are signed by the node issuing the invoice in order to verify the signature we need to know the node id. Thus it is included in the invoice. Lightning nodes provide an API to decode invoices.

**In c-lightning you can do** (lnd below!)

```
lightning-cli decodepay LNBC13934430N1PWJUJEZPP5K7FLC2M5CLHTWMTF3HZDN7VVRCA4RNFAFA89F2D6KGYWW4JCSDAQDZ62PSKJEPQW3HJQ4RGV5SYC6T8DP6XU6TWVUSYXMMWVEJHYETWVDJJQ2Z0WFJX2U3QF9ZR5GZ5F3PNZWFD25UY54Z39YXQZURCQP2RZJQG8ZM9WXGVHZPMUQEWY9J9KDQNRVLZHPCWM6S8CVLC2CKRDNELE42Z9U5VQQY3SQQYQQQQL8QQQQPJQQ9Q6KM84F7KTW6UV574UR2LFNKZLM7VNK8NJRZV20JD8SAW6FZ3TQGSZE6YUT0X2UXGDGYJZGTXEFSQSSEVTKFF97P3TER5K23ZPHDDXHQQ95UT4N
{
  "currency": "bc", 
  "created_at": 1563314978, 
  "expiry": 899, 
  "payee": "024a8228d764091fce2ed67e1a7404f83e38ea3c7cb42030a2789e73cf3b341365", 
  "msatoshi": 1393443000, 
  "amount_msat": "1393443000msat", 
  "description": "Paid to The Lightning Conference (Order ID: TLC19-U8JTQ)", 
  "min_final_cltv_expiry": 10, 
  "routes": [
    [
      {
        "pubkey": "020e2d95c6432e20ef80cb885916cd04c6cf8ae1c3b7a81f0cfe158b0db3cff355", 
        "short_channel_id": "572579x582x1", 
        "fee_base_msat": 999, 
        "fee_proportional_millionths": 200, 
        "cltv_expiry_delta": 40
      }
    ]
  ], 
  "payment_hash": "b793fc2b74c7eeb76d698dc4d9f98c1e3b51cd3d4f4e54a9bab208e75658837a", 
  "signature": "3045022100d5b67aa7d65bb5c653d5e0d5f4cec2fefcc9d8f390c4c53e4d3c3aed245158110220016744e2de6570c86a09212166ca6008432c5d9292f8315e474b2a220ddad35c"
}
```

In particular we find the entry which reveals the node of the store:

```
 "payee": "024a8228d764091fce2ed67e1a7404f83e38ea3c7cb42030a2789e73cf3b341365"
```

We can query the gossip store for more information about the node with the following command:

```
lightning-cli listnodes | grep 024a8228d764091fce2ed67e1a7404f83e38ea3c7cb42030a2789e73cf3b341365 -B 1 -C 13
    {
      "nodeid": "024a8228d764091fce2ed67e1a7404f83e38ea3c7cb42030a2789e73cf3b341365", 
      "alias": "www.fulmo.org", 
      "color": "f2f3f4", 
      "last_timestamp": 1561973177, 
      "globalfeatures": "", 
      "global_features": "", 
      "addresses": [
        {
          "type": "ipv4", 
          "address": "95.211.207.81", 
          "port": 9735
        }
      ]
    },
```

This gives us all the information we need to peer with the shop and fund a channel.  (In case the node was private we could use the `routes` hints from the decoded invoice to connect to a public exit node.)

**lnd users**

If you are using `lnd` you can use the command `DecodePayReq` and instead of invoking `listnodes` to get the information from the gossip store you can invoke `GetNetworkInfo`

Comment: Also note that the `payee` field in a BOLT 11 invoice is optional. If omitted, the signing node's public key can be recovered from the signature and the recovery id. I am not sure whether the implementations will automatically fill in the `payee` field in this case when using `decodepay`/`DecodePayReq`.

Comment: I was not aware that pub keys can be computed from signatures in ecdsa. If others are surprised too look at  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/how-does-recovering-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-signature-work to see why / how this is possible.